# How to obtain media_url of all images in an album using Instagram Graph API?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, pagination, instagram

I'm trying to get all the media urls/source urls from an album post (carousel post) on Instagram. I'm able to get only the first image from the album.

The below url fetches the list of messages from the particular thread along with their ids.

```
messages_list = f"https://graph.facebook.com/{GRAPH_API_VERSION}/{thread_id}?fields=messages&platform=instagram&access_token={access_token}"
```

This fetches the details of a particular message id.

```
message_details = f"https://graph.facebook.com/{GRAPH_API_VERSION}/{message_id}?fields={fields}&platform=instagram&access_token={access_token}"
```

The response I get from the `message_details` GET request for an album post is shown in the screenshot attached below. As you can see it shows only the link to the first image that is present in the album at the top and below it shows the link to `next` and `previous` endpoints.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRjR4.png)

After accessing the `next` endpoint from the previous result, this is what I got.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KBNR.png)

Comment: _"After accessing the next endpoint from the previous result, this is what I got."_ - that looks like you simply copy&pasted this from the result - instead of actually decoding the JSON?

Comment: Yes, I did copy and pasted it from the "next" endpoint, but what do you mean by decoding the JSON?

Comment: What you got back from the API, is JSON. Including additional escaping in several places, like those `\u...` sequences. Decoding the JSON and accessing the _original_ value might help.

Answer (score 0):

To see all the images in a feed post you can use

```
{api_version}/{post_id}?fields=media_url,children{media_url}
```

- `media_url` is the link to the first image
- `children{media_url}` are the links for all the images on the post